# Computing range, null space, and matrix of a linear transformation

Tags: real-analysis, transformation

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be defined by $(a_1, a_2, a_3) \mapsto (a_1, a_2, -a_1-a_2)$. I have to find $R(T), N(T)$ and a matrix that represents $T$.
I know for my matrix that represents $T$ it will look something like this:
$$
T=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-1 & -1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but I have no idea how to find the range and null space of $T$. I tried proving linearity and I couldn't even do that. The $-a_1 - a_2$ was throwing me off because it wasn't in terms of $a_3$ so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: [Here's a guide on how to type math using Mathjax.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: As a first step, try writing down the definitions of range, null space and linearity.

Comment: I know the definitions. I don't know how to apply the T to them.

Answer (score 0):

To find the null space literally set your ordered triple equal to zero and determine what are the valid values of $a_1, a_2, a_3$ need to be in order for the image to be (0,0,0).

Determining the null space of this linear transformation should tell you a lot about the range. Hint: What is required of the null space for the transformation to be injective?

Comment: Is it required in this question to show the linearity because that is what I had most trouble with.

Comment: To show that it is in fact linear just show that $T(cx+y)=cT(x)+T(y)$ where c is a scalar, and x and y are ordered triples in $\mathbb{R}^3$